# How do I search for a word or a phrase in the Linux 'man' command and cycle through the found solutions?

Tags: linux, unix, man

When looking for a certain word or phrase in the man page of Linux command, one can type '/' followed by the word or phrase to search for it.

What I'd like to be able to do is to search for the next occurrence of the word or phrase without having to type it out again. Kinda like when you use <kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd></kbd>  in a browser to search for a word, and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to find the next occurrence of that word.

If this is possible to do, how do I do it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> for the next and previous matches.

(The default pager used for manual pages is *less*, which has similar shortcuts to those in the *vim* text editor.)

Comment: `less` does not start continue in the beginning after it reaches the bottom. To move up, either press `Home` or `P`.

Answer (score 24):

Type `/` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>; an empty regex always means the previous successfully matched regex.

Comment: Or you can just press `n` for the same effect.