# How do I cycle through from top to bottom when passing a pattern in command: in Linux?

Tags: linux, man

I came across the post at [How do I search for a word or a phrase in the Linux 'man' command and cycle through the found solutions?](https://superuser.com/questions/304065/linux-man-command-how-do-i-search-for-a-word-phrase-and-cycle-through) which explains the ability to cycle to the next pattern but how do I get it cycle through when it has passed the a pattern assuming it only occurs once or when I get to the bottom of the page?

For example once I have run the command `man dpkg` I pass `/` followed by `simulate`. This takes me to the pattern however it only works when I am the top of the page. If I am past the pattern, it does recursively search the entire man page.

Comment: The question you link to has the answer. Read the comments to the accepted answer.

Comment: Recursive doesn't mean what you think.

Comment: @Mat - I did read the accepted answer but it doesn't start from the top again if I have scrolled down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - Sorry. What do you mean?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: The answer suggests just pressing `Home` or `p` to go to the beginning when you hit the end. The next search will then be from the beginning. `g` also works (and is similar to Vim, so that is what I use when in `less`).

Comment: @Daniel Andersson - Thanks Daniel. Is there no way I can achieve it without pressing `Home` or `p`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey For some man pages I'm often reading and searching thru like `bash` I saved a copy to a textfile with `man bash | col -b >bash.txt` and then `vi bash.txt`. A disadvantage is you need to redo that when a new version of bash is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man` does not have an option to continue searching at the top of page once you reach the bottom, so pressing <kbd>p</kbd> is your option, or <kbd>Shift-n</kbd> to search backwards.

man uses `less` to do its paging, and `less` doesn't support cycling that way.  So you could look at getting man to use something other than less for paging [such as vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_a_man-page_viewer_under_Unix).  Or alternatively, install the vim `man` plugin and run man from [within a vim session](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_man_pages_in_Vim):

```
:Man dpkg
```